# My vue component shows white writing almost as if it hasnt been turned on,what could be the problem

Tags: laravel

**Here is my Vue component,** It is the section where the code is in white

```
<template>

  <div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 40px" @click="followUser">Follow</button>

  </div> 
</template>


    

    <script>
    export default {

    props:['userId'],
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        methods:{

        followUser(){

        axios.post('/follow/1')
          .then(reponse=> {
              alert(response.data);
           }); 
        }
    }

}

        
    
</script>
```

***The App.js***

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');



// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('follow-button', require('./components/FollowButton.vue').default);



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

***The Bootstrap.js***

```
window._ = require('lodash');



try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     forceTLS: true
// });
```

when i run my application in the server,it works though the writings are still in white.Should i be concerned with that?

Also my axios.post method in the Vue component does not work,it is supposed to show a message box with the words success,i'll post the file with all the routes below

**web.php**

```
  Route::get('/','PicturesController@index' );

Auth::routes();
 


Route::get('/p/create','PicturesController@create');//this route directs you to add a picture




Route::post('/p','PicturesController@store');//this route stores a picture

Route::post('/follow/{user}',function(){
    return ['success'];
});



Route::get('/changeProfile/create','changeprofiles@create');//this route changes a profile 

Route::post('/changeProfile','changeprofiles@store');//this route stores a changed profile





Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'profilesController@index')->name('profile.show');//this route shows the users account

Route::get('/p/{picture}','PicturesController@show');//this route displays a posted image on the screen. 

Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit','ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');//allows you to edit your profile


Route::patch('/profile/{user}','ProfilesController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

Comment: See console you will see some error there

Comment: The console seems to be okay,i ran npm run watch and it compiled successfully @ashokpoudel

Comment: How are you doing your front-end routing? I see you don't have your router object in your  root instance. That is  `const app = new Vue({ ... })`.

Comment: Typically there should be error on console in this case . I have also faced it but there is always error on console

Comment: i'm using axios.post(follow/1) to pass the route to my front-end,the route is a post,it's in the web.php@Tony

Comment: do you think there's a package i need to install or import to the vue component or app.js?